# How to extract one level from json response and display it separatedly as independent data - C# .net core

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, httpclient, response

I'm working with `.net core app`, without frontend, so all of the code is on server.

here is server's response after`HttpClient` call:

```
 {
        "productId": null,
        "email": "demo@gmail.com",
        "position": null,
        "title": "demo@gmail.com",
        "price": null,
        "product_metadata": 
        {
            "organization": 
            {
                "organizationId": "",
                "title": null
            },
            "sale_stores": 
            [
                {
                    "storeId": "1",
                    "title": null
                },
                {
                    "storeId": "2",
                    "title": null
                }
            ],
        }
    },
```

I'm calling external API to get data so I can't influence what response I will get after I call exteral server. But I can modify this respone on my server ofcourse.

And I would like to get rid of  `"product_metadata"` level so I could create a response for client
(which will join later) which could look like this:

```
  {
        "productId": null,
        "email": "demo@gmail.com",
        "position": null,
        "title": "demo@gmail.com",
        "price": null,
        "organization": 
        {
           "organizationId": "",
           "title": null
        },
        "sale_stores": 
        [
            {
                "storeId": "1",
                "title": null
            },
            {
                "storeId": "2",
                "title": null
            }
         ],
    },
```

Here's my code - ***please read comments :***

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<ProductDto>> GetProducts(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{

    var response = await _Client.Get<List<ProductDto>>(url, accessToken, cancellationToken);
    // Somewhere in this Get method call I'm deserializing data to my Dto 
    // return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(result); < - this happening in Get method

    // Here I need to modify this response to rid of that one level that I dont need 
    // Maybe I can loop results and move it to another Dto without `product_metadata` level but that's performance issue?
    
    return response;
}
```

Here's my `ProductDto`

```
public class ProductDto
{
    public string ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("product_metadata")]
    public ProductMetadataDto ProductMetadata { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks guys

Cheers

Comment: You will not have any performance issue by mapping it to another DTO, go for it! :) It's somewhat of a best practice to map to your own models that you control and return from your API.

Comment: @JOSEFtw If I use classing foreach loop I'm afraid in case of for example 1000 products It might take some time. Is there any faster way to remap it? :P

Comment: I can ensure you that it will not be a problem. Try it out and measure it :). If we are talking about responses in the size of 10 000 or more items, then you should really think about pagination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not have any performance issue by mapping it to another DTO, go for it! :) It's somewhat of a best practice to map to your own models that you control and return from your API.
Do something like this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<MyProductDto>> GetProducts(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var response = await _Client.Get<List<ProductDto>>(url, accessToken, cancellationToken);
    var mappedResponse = myMapper.Map(response);
    return mappedResponse;
}
```

If you have a bunch of products, like 10000 or more, you should really look into pagination :)

Comment: but response will be list for example with 1000 items , and that's ok?

Comment: When you have the objects in "response". Mapping it to a new DTO will not give you perfomance issue, even if you have 500k objects in the list.